# Power Apps Filter Gallery data using checkbox

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-canvas

I'm trying to filter my gallery data taken from SharePoint list "HelpDesk".

Initially I used a Combobox to filter the gallery based on selected "RequestType" from the Combobox.

Later I used Checkbox control to filter gallery based on the "RequestType" checkboxes selected.

I am able to filter the gallery using the combobox control. But when I try to filter the gallery on selecting the Checkboxes , my gallery is blank . No data is displayed

This is my SharePoint list

[image]

This is my app

[image]

This is my code to filter the Gallery

> Filter(
> HelpDesk,
> IsBlank(ReqComboBox.SelectedItems.Value) || IsEmpty(ReqComboBox.SelectedItems) || RequestType in  ReqComboBox.SelectedItems
> )

Items property of Combobox ---- Choices(HelpDesk.RequestType)

DefaultSelectedItems Property of Combobox ----- colReq.Value

OnCheck Property of Checkbox ----- Collect(colReq,ThisItem)

OnUncheck Property of Checkbox ----- Remove(colReq,ThisItem)

On selecting the checkboxes , the values are being displayed in the Combobox but my gallery is blank

[image]

On inspecting the screen shows the error as shown below

[image]